# uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement

Tags: ruby, postgresql, activerecord, sinatra

Im currently working on a sinatra app, and im having a trouble regarding postgresql connection to sinatra, im try to execute this command:

> rake db:create

to create the database but it throws this error.

```
C:\Users\John\Documents\Registration_Sinatra>rake db:create
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement
C:/Users/John/Documents/Registration_Sinatra/app/app.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Users/John/Documents/Registration_Sinatra/Rakefile:1:in `<top (required)>'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- sinatra/activerecord
C:/Users/John/Documents/Registration_Sinatra/app/app.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Users/John/Documents/Registration_Sinatra/Rakefile:1:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

this is my app.rb

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/activerecord'
require 'pg'
require './config/environments'
class RegistrationSinatra < ActiveRecord::Base
end 
get '/' do
erb :index
end
```

this is my environments.rb

```
configure :development do
@DEFAULT_CONN = {database: 'development_registration_sinatra', user: 'postgres', password: 'secret123', host: 'localhost'}
db = URI.parse(ENV['DATABASE_URL'] || "postgres://#{@DEFAULT_CONN[:host]}/#{@DEFAULT_CONN[:database]}?user=#{@DEFAULT_CONN[:user]}")
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
:adapter  => db.scheme == 'postgres' ? 'postgresql' : db.scheme,
:host     => @DEFAULT_CONN[:host],
:username => @DEFAULT_CONN[:user],
:password => @DEFAULT_CONN[:password],
:database => db.path[1..-1],
:encoding => 'utf8')
end
```

this is my gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "2.2.2"
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'activerecord'
gem 'sinatra-activerecord'
gem 'tux'
gem 'pg'
```

and my Rakefile

```
require './app/app'
require 'sinatra/activerecord/rake'
```

hope you guys can pin point what's wrong with my sample app so i can progress thanks.

Comment: Did you run `bundle install` or `bundle exec`? If yes, then `bundle exec rake -T`.

Comment: yes i did both, and it gives me an error also. which is cannot find sinatra/activerecord

Comment: How about changing `sinatra-activerecord` to `sinatra/activerecord`

Comment: when i try to bundle install, it throws another error: Could not find gem 'sinatra/activerecord x64-mingw32' in any of the gem sources

Comment: Apologies, I said it for `require sinatra-activerecord` not in your gem file. Now run `bundle install` and then `bundle exec rake db:create`

Comment: it's weird. yesterday it is working now it isn't, btw i followed your instruction and it worked. but when i execute the command "rackup" it throws an error, but when i append bundle exec to the rackup it runs, what seems to be the problem with that? i got confused because yesterday it is working with the rackup command only

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Basic Sinatra app with ActiveRecord and getting the error `uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement`. Any solution?

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution: https://github.com/janko-m/sinatra-activerecord/pull/66

In your Gemfile, add:

`gem "activerecord", "< 5.0.0"`

run `bundle update` and it will work.